Class Based View for User Registraion using Django
Which Class Based View is perfect for User Registration ?
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
or
from django.views import View
Is there any other Class Based View for User Registration ?

i think you search https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views
And for registration you can use CreateView with UserCreationForm together:
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class SingUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    model = get_user_model()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

I understand why a direct "UserRegistrationGCBView" doesn't exist - too many different cases in the registration process in each project.
I improved SingUpView according to the standard django.contrib.auth logic. First - registration, then - login. Of course, the login url should be registered.

What is the form_valid doing here? It seems like you first save the form, to then do it a second time? Normally the form should already be validated?

@willeM_VanOnsem I tested this on an empty project, and provided a better solution. But in the previous version, you didn't recognize that the second time I call form_valid from LoginView and not from SingUpView. I know OOP, it's not simple.

After some research, I improved SingUpView and made it shorter. I think it better fits the ideas of django.
